# Writing to the previous line of a txt file in Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, python-3.3

I have a .txt with alternating names and numbers (the numbers ordered from lowest to highest). I then have 2 variables, an integer and a name. 
I want to search the .txt for the 1st number that is >= to my integer variable and then I want to write my integer and name above the found number (I need them on a new line, and each variable on a separate line).

This is what I have so far:

```
import re

new_num = 456
new_data = str(new_num) + '\n' + 'Georph'
written = False

with open('line_search.txt','r+') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(data):
        number = (re.findall("\d+", line))
        if number:
            if new_num <= int(number[0]):
                while written == False:
                    written = True
                    print(number[0])
                    print("print 2 lines right before this line")
                    f.writelines(new_data)
```

And this is the test .txt being searched:

```
65
Munkshunk
164
Nimaman
649
Tila
891
Mugshoe
```

Which I **want** to end up looking like this:

```
65
Munkshunk
164
Nimaman
456
Georph
649
Tila
891
Mugshoe
```

But so far the script only appends my 2 variables **to the end of the .txt**, how do I make it insert it the line before the found variable?

Comment: You need to write to a new file.

Comment: In order to write out lines in a different order you'll need to store the lines (or their indexes).  Then you can *redorder* once you've parsed the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If memory consumption and time is not a problem the easiest is to read all data from file, change data and overwrite file with new data:

```
import re

new_num = 456
new_data = str(new_num) + '\n' + 'Georph\n'
written = False

with open('line_search.txt','r') as f:
    data = f.readlines()
updated_data = []
for i, line in enumerate(data):
    if re.match("\d+", line):
        if new_num <= int(line):
            updated_data = data[:i] + [new_data] + data[i:]
            break
with open('line_search.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.writelines(updated_data)
```

Comment: Is there an advantage to doing it your way over using the `fileinput` module?

Comment: I don't think using fileinput module for this task is a good idea

Comment: I appreciate the feedback, but without reasoning I'm not learning or able to determine when to use `fileinput` in the future. Why is it not a good idea for this task?

Comment: from docs for `fileinput`: "This module implements a helper class and functions to quickly write a loop over standard input or a list of files. If you just want to read or write one file see open()."

Comment: in this case is it necessary to finish the file with `f.close()` or does it not really open the file to memory and just store the f.readlines() to data?

Comment: if you use `with` block there is no need to close file, it is closed automatically then execution goes out of `with` block http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wants to use the `fileinput` method, here is what I came up with:

```
import re
import fileinput

new_num = 456
new_data = str(new_num) + '\n' + 'Georph'
written = False


for line in fileinput.input('line_search.txt', inplace=1):
    number = (re.findall("\d+", line))
    if number:
        if new_num <= int(number[0]):
            while written == False:
                written = True
                print(new_data)
    print(line.strip('\n')) #without the .strip('\n') the file get's re-written for some reason with a '\n' between every single line in the document.
```

Comment: print adds its own '\n' and as you already have '\n' in your `line` you get'\n\n', you can use print with `end=''` keyword http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#print